# Align bottom of a view to the center of ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view, android-constraintlayout

I have a custom view that I want to place inside a `ConstraintLayout` so that its bottom is at the center of the `ConstraintLayout`.

The child view has a dynamic height with `wrap_content`, so I can't easily set a fixed margin or padding.

I know that I can align the center of the view with the center of the `ConstraintLayout` using

```
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
```

but as I said I want to align the bottom of the view with the center of the `ConstraintLayout`.

Any good way to accomplish this?

Comment: You can use guideline in a centre by keeping it 50% and then align your view bottom to the top of the guideline

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a `Guideline` to add extra constraint to your layout, like this:

```
<android.support.constraint.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.5"/>
```

, and then **align** your view with this guideline like this:

```
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline"
```